# Insert a String at the beginning of the array without losing the String at the first position

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to insert a String into the first place at the array. When I tried to insert the string everything goes fine, but when I try to insert an another string it seems that the first string gets deleted from the array. I don't know why it's doing this.

```
var History: [String] = []

self.History.insert("\(Username_1)", at: self.History.startIndex)
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(self.History, forKey: "SavedStringHistory")
```

Here I am trying to insert the String called "Username_1" at the begin of the array and than save it.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let myhistory = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringHistory") ?? [String]()
let history = myhistory[indexPath.row]
```

This is how I retrieve the data in the Array. What I think is going on is that the existed String in the array get replaced by the new one. But I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: In your example you're instantiating a new `history: [String]`, inserting one element and then saving it to the user defaults. It would only ever have one element in it. You would need to first instantiate it with whatever is in the `UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringHistory")` then do the insert then do the `set` to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The `History` array as declared by these two lines:

```
var History: [String] = []
...
self.History.insert("\(Username_1)", at: self.History.startIndex)
```

contains one element, that is `"\(Username_1)"`.

When you set the entry in the user defaults that has `"SavedStringHistory"` as key, it replaces whatever was there before.

```
defaults.set(self.History, forKey: "SavedStringHistory")
```

Instead what you want to do is keep the previously stored values, if any, by changing the declaration of `History` to the same that you've given to `myhistory`:

```
var History: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringHistory") ?? [String]()
```